# PHP: Generate Image Thumbnail from .PDF, .DOC, and .DOCX in Linux

Tags: php, imagemagick, docx, doc

As the title says,

I'm essentially looking for a way to generate a thumbnail from a .DOC, .DOCX, or .PDF file uploaded to the linux machine.

I understand ImageMagick can handle .PDF to .PNG conversion and is made even easier with PHP's IMagick but I am unsure about .DOC or .DOCX. I think I was told a headless version of OpenOffice can do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829847/linux-based-ms-office-thumbnail-generation   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=76566

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tested it myself yet however ooo-thumbnailer can apparently make thumbnails of DOC, DOCX and PDF files from version .31 and up.

The project is available from here: https://launchpad.net/ooo-thumbnailer

This is a subject that I've spent a long time searching myself and it seems that this is probably your best bet.

Comment: For DOC/DOCX this doesn't create the previews it just displays already existing ones embed in the file by MSOffice.